# merge result of two joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables: Book, Invoice, Download where the last two have foreign key to Book. I need to know number of successful invoices and downloads for each book. To get the result, I have 2 queries. The first one displays number invoices for each book:

```
select b.Title, sum(i.price)
from Book b, Invoice i
where i.BookId = b.Id and i.State = 'successful'
group by b.Title
```

And the last one displays number downloads for each book:

```
select b.Title, count(1)
from Book b, Download d 
where d.BookId = b.Id and d.State = 'successful'
group by b.FarsiTitle
```

I want to see the result as a single table, so that I have 3 columns:

> book_title, invoice_count, download_count

How is it possible?

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But why should I use `JOIN` instead of extending `from`?

Comment: Commas in the `FROM` clause are archaic syntax that is not as powerful as `JOIN`.  We are in the 21st Century, so we should use the modern, standard SQL language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is correlated subqueries:

```
select b.*,
       (select count(*)
        from invoice i
        where i.BookId = b.Id and i.State = 'successful'
       ) as num_invoices,
       (select count(*)
        from download d
        where d.BookId = b.Id and d.State = 'successful'
       ) as numdownloads
from book b;
```

If you want to use `JOIN`, then you need to aggregate *before* the `JOIN` to get the right counts.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, you can use `outer apply`

```
select b.*, i.num_invoices, i.price, d.numdownloads
from book b outer apply
     (select count(*) as num_invoices, sum(i.price) as price
      from invoice i
      where i.BookId = b.Id and i.State = 'successful'
     ) i outer apply
     (select count(*) as numdownloads
      from download d
      where d.BookId = b.Id and d.State = 'successful'
     ) d;
```

This is very similar to the correlated subquery, but allows you to do multiple calculations.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be correct. So I can put `group by` clause after `from Book b` and put other conditions on Book in a where clause. But this doesn't make any performance issues?

Comment: @AbouzarNouri . . . No `group by` is necessary.  You can just add `where` conditions on `book` after the `from` clause.

Comment: I have an extra question! If I want to have sum(i.Price) in addition to total number of invoices for each book, is it possible to extend this query or I should add a third `select` clause?

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

A simple union all is fine as below:

```
select b.Title, sum(i.price)
from Book b join Invoice i
on i.BookId = b.Id and i.State = 'successful'
group by b.Title

UNION ALL

select b.Title, count(1)
from Book b join Download d 
on d.BookId = b.Id and d.State = 'successful'
group by b.FarsiTitle
```

Comment: I think this is wrong. Since I need to merge the results based on book title so to have three columns.